# Multibranch job does not trigger when using scripted syntax in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I am having a multibranch pipeline with two branches(branches of product repo) master and qac.

Both the branches (i.e. master and qac) have jenkinsfile.

When using declarative syntax in the jenkinsfile, the job triggers on git push.

Below is the declarative Jenkinsfile

```
library(
  identifier: 'jenkins-library@master',
  retriever: modernSCM(
    [
      $class: 'GitSCMSource',
      remote: 'https://github.com/ABC/Jenkins-CommonLib.git',
      credentialsId: '2023203e3-a0da-445c-ab1c-1d26a416e3f8'
    ]
  )
)
properties([pipelineTriggers([githubPush()])])
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {

    stage('Stage 1') {
      steps {
        script {
          echo 'Stage 1'
        }
      }
    }
}
}
```

however, when using scripted jenkinsfile, the job is not triggered on git push but the Push event is recieved by jenkins(found in the jenkins logs)

Below is the scripted jenkinsfile

```
library(
identifier: 'jenkins-library@master',
retriever: modernSCM(
[
$class: 'GitSCMSource',
remote: 'https://github.com/ABC/Jenkins-CommonLib.git',
credentialsId: '20860d33-a0da-445c-ab1c-1d26a416e3f8'
]
)
)
properties([pipelineTriggers([githubPush()])])
node {
serviceAppBuild{}
}
```

ServiceAppBuild is a groovy file in the shared library that actually contains the pipeline stages.

How to trigger the build using the scripted jenkinsfile ?